# Process shell exited abnormally with code 53 on windows 10

Tags: microsoft-windows, shell, process

I'm using emacs 26.2 installed through msys2.

Recently starting subprocesses from emacs has stopped working for me. Specifically `M-x shell` and `shell-command-to-string`.

I get the feeling this is due to a windows update or something since I didn't update emacs when this problem started occurring.
I'm on the Windows 10 beta channel running version 20H2 at the moment.

Now when I do `M-x shell` I get this error message: `Process shell exited abnormally with code 53`.
If I call `shell-command-to-string` I just get an empty string as a reply. No matter what the argument.

Has anyone else seen this problem?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328079/grep-failing-with-emacs-windows-and-gnuwin32-grep   Can you run the shell from the command prompt?

Comment: Thanks that got me on the right track. It seems the issue was cmdproxy complaining about libssp-0.dll. If I copied libssp-0.dll from mingw64/bin to mingw64/libexec/emacs/26.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32 it started working again.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the issue was cmdproxy.exe complaining about not being able to find libssp-0.dll.

As a workaround copy libssp-0.dll from mingw64/bin to mingw64/libexec/emacs/26.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32.